# Can a Shopify app access any Analytical reports from a merchant's store or only the custom reports which were created through API by the app?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Can a Shopify app access any Analytical reports from a merchant's store or only the custom reports which were created through API by the app , [see here](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-07/resources/report) ? and if yes then how can we access that in php

Answer (score 1):

You are free to follow Shopify developer practices and to access store data using https://shopify.dev/api/shopifyql

Not sure what your question is, but PHP certainly has nothing to do with it, as any and all data API requests with Shopify are scripting language agnostic. In other words, if you can authenticate and you're authorized, make some API calls for data and do your work as per usual.